# How can I dynamically customize the product version in the MSI file properties with Installshield

Tags: installshield, basic-msi

I'm using Installshield 2019 to generate a basic MSI file.
I want to customize the file properties that are displayed in the windows explorer file properties (in the details tab => title, subject, comments)
Sadly (and strangely), the Product Version does not appear in my generated MSI file's props, and I would like to have at least one file property with the product version.

Constraint: It is automated => **I'm using the command line with IsBuildCmd.exe to pass the product version.**

In the General Information panel of my project I can define a few values they are mapped to "Strings" (and not properties). 
In the release information it is the same, I can override the file properties values, but they are mapped to "strings".

1/ I don't manage to map those values to properties

2/ I did not find anything to override "Strings" from the command line

Thanks for your help

Comment: in my eyes it is an installshield defect, the ability to pass the "product version" as a parameter should not prevent from setting this value into the file properties. It should work naturally... case opened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a little tough but I think you can control this using the [IsWiProject COM interface](https://docs.flexera.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm). With this you can dynamically set the ProductVersion property for the project.

Comment: This is the solution according to Flexera support.
Finally I did not use the InstallShield COM interface. Our build chains were already using ISBuildCmd.exe and that was a bit too much for us to change it all.
We finally used a small utility from the Windows SDK call "MsiInfo.exe" that easily did the job. Just after the MSI has been generated by InstallShield, we patch the Comment property with the product name and version.
MsiInfo.exe "MyProduct.msi" /O "MyProduct v1.200.000"
That was the easiest for us!

Answer (score 0):

Try these old answers:

- [**On Installshield Build Automation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281613/installshield-build-automation). *`IsCmdBld.exe`*, *`InstallShield Automation Interface`*, *`MsBuild.exe`*, *`etc...`* - make sure to read [**the actual answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295611/129130).
- [**Installshield COM Automation**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022528/how-to-change-product-code-programmatically)
- [**Chris Painter on COM automation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2197036/129130) (scroll up to see question details)

Short answer is that there are various options here to review. Be aware that there are some persistent bugs here and there, have a good read of the answers - particularly the problems described in the second one. Maybe run a smoke test.

---

***Further Links***:

- https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Forum/Command-Line-build-questions-Basic-MSI/td-p/35985
- [Old answer on automation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30014138/129130)